# Comparison between dates starts with -1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame ({
    'Date':['4/22/2020 14:32:10','4/21/2020 4:32:10','4/20/2020 1:32:10']
    })

date ='04/22/2020'

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
days_diff = (datetime_object - df['Date']).dt.days

print(days_diff)
0   -1
1    0
2    1
```

Why the result is not looking like the one below? Why the no of days starts with **-1** and not with **0**?

```
0   0
1   1
2   2
```

Comment: I can do smth like this: days_diff +=1. But this doesn't explain to me what it's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because it's flooring the answers

```
for the first case 

'4/22/2020 14:32:10' the diff is  =  -14/ 24 = ~ -0.6 days
o/p:- -1

for the second case
'4/21/2020 4:32:10' the diff is  =  20/24 = ~ 0.8 days 
o/p:- 0

for the third case
'4/20/2020 1:32:10' the difff is = 47/24  =  ~1.9 days
o/p:- 1
```

I hope it helps.

Solution would be convert all the datetimes to dates
as in following line i have done with 'Date' column

```
days_diff = (datetime_object.date() - df['Date'].dt.date ).dt.days


In [32]: days_diff
Out[32]:
0    0
1    1
2    2
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is to do with the fact you are subtracting the higher date from the lower date which leaves you with a negative result. In the datetime module, subtracting one date object from another creates a time delta object like so

```py
         days1 = self.toordinal()
        days2 = other.toordinal()
        secs1 = self._second + self._minute * 60 + self._hour * 3600
        secs2 = other._second + other._minute * 60 + other._hour * 3600
        base = timedelta(days1 - days2,
                         secs1 - secs2,
                         self._microsecond - other._microsecond)
```

If we mimic that with your dates we see the following days and secs created for each date object

```
737537 0
737537 52330
```

subtracting day2 from days1 and secs2 form secs 1 means we pass the following to the timedelta object

```
0 -52330
```

So we are saying create a time delta object where the difference is 0 days and negative 52,330 seconds. Which is quite correct. However the timedelta object is a complex object and allows fractional values, and also many other types, like weeks or minutes etc. it also does not apply any limits to the values. so in the seconds part you can pass 10 seconds or 100,000 seconds. Now 100,000 seconds is actually more seconds than there are in a day. So the code takes this into account and will divmod the seconds to work out if there are any extra days in these seconds.

```py
        days, seconds = divmod(seconds, 24*3600)
        d += days
        s += int(seconds)    # can't overflow
```

Now Here the issue lies in understanding what divmod does. div mod will do a floor division and remainder of the calculation. Now in a positive case thats fine.

```py
print(divmod(52330, 24*3600))
print(divmod(-52330, 24*3600))

(0, 52330)
(-1, 34070)
```

Since the floor division will round down to 0 days and return you the remaining seconds. However in the negative case the floor division will round down to -1 since -52330 / 86400 is -0.6056.... So floor division rounds this down to -1 and the remainder is the difference between between 86400 and 52330 so leaves 34070 seconds.

So you wouldnt face this issue if you are always subtracting the oldest date from the newest date so you never end up with a negative difference. Infact it doesnt make sense to subtract a newer date from an older date.

for the other cases you listed the difference between 4/21/2020 4:32:10 and 4/22/2020 00:00:00 is indeed 0 days since the difference is actually only 20 hours, this behavior is correct the difference is not 1 days its 20 hours.